# i am using datetime picker and want that my start and end date must have difference of 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Start time is :- 02/18/2014 11:00
End time is :-02/27/2014 09:33
I want to calculate the difference between 2 dates using jquery
so that I can add validation that user must keep the difference of 24 hour (1day) while selecting the date.

Comment: Okay, good luck. Come back with some code when you got problems.

Comment: how can I calculate the difference using jquery

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

this is the jquery

```
var start = new Date("2014-02-18");
var end = new Date();
var diff = new Date(end - start);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24
//alert(days);
if(days<=1){
    alert("less then 1 day");
}
else{
    alert("more then 1 day");
}
```

this is the jsfiddle for it

http://jsfiddle.net/3QAJa/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var start_actual_time  =  "02/18/2014 11:00";
var end_actual_time    =  "02/27/2014 09:33";

start_actual_time = new Date(start_actual_time);
end_actual_time = new Date(end_actual_time);

var diff = end_actual_time - start_actual_time;

var diffSeconds = diff/1000;
var HH = Math.floor(diffSeconds/3600);
var MM = Math.floor(diffSeconds%3600)/60;

var formatted = ((HH < 10)?("0" + HH):HH) + ":" + ((MM < 10)?("0" + MM):MM)
alert(formatted);
```